# SPI Slave sometimes sends incorrect data

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, spi, communication, arm

I apologize in advance if I should have not created a new thread as I ran through new issues after making updates to my project posted on this previous thread: [SPI data arrives at every 2nd send and in the wrong sequence](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/509826/spi-data-arrives-at-every-2nd-send-and-in-the-wrong-sequence?noredirect=1#comment1306232_509826)

I made several changes to the previous project to address the SPI sync issues between the STM32F3 slave and STM32F4 master. I also made changes to the code based on suggestions under that thread: mainly making the ISRs shorter and placing most of the data processing in the main loop.

The screenshot of the logic analyzer below is what I am trying to achieve with the SPI transaction:

[image: Desired SPI communication]

**Explanation of the process:** In the screenshot above, the STM32F4 master sends a command byte (0xE1) and discards a temporary value (0x99). Afterwards the STM32F3 slave will respond with the following bytes based on the received 0xE1: 0xEB, 0x00, 0xCC, 0x01 in that following order, while the STM32F4 master sends temporary values to get data from the STM32F3 slave. There is a small delay between the first byte and the remaining 4 bytes to give leeway for the STM32F3 Slave to configure the data to be sent based on the command. The delay also serves as a debounce mechanism for the Master's push button (the Master sends SPI data when the user button is pressed - GPIO interrupt).

Sometimes, I get the waveform above through the logic analyzer. Other times, I get garbage bits like the one below:

[image: Error example 1]

[image: Error example 2]

And a combination of shifted data and incorrect data like below:

[image: Shifted data]

[image: Shifted data and inaccurate data]

**What I did differently from the previous thread:** I made the ISR code shorter and did most of the process in the main loop. I also had many more sync issues which I got rid of by increasing the STM32F3 system clock from 8MHz to 64MHz (in hopes that the slave does all the data processing faster and can set up the `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT()` faster before the Master performs the `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive()` to obtain the 4 bytes from the slave. Regarding the SPI protocol, I matched the APB2 peripheral bus speeds to 4MHz, and I also used a large SPI Baudrate Prescaler to make the SPI speed slower.

**My suspected cause of issues:** I read on some of the ST community threads that the HAL drivers are buggy. I also tried  a custom `ExchangeSpiBits()` code posted somewhere in an ST thread but that also did not work. I also looked at this thread: [STM32 SPI Slave send data Problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/324439/stm32-spi-slave-send-data-problem) and I might be forgetting to clear some flags (although I believe HAL does that automatically, and I could not find TEIE flag on my STM32F3).

**What I tried that did not work:** Making the SPI speed lower than it is currently did not work (although the results were better now than it was when SPI was running at 8MHz). Changing the GPIO output speed (associated with the SPI Slave pins) from high, medium, and slow did not work. Using `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT()` to instead send the 4 bytes from the slave when it receives 4 bytes from the master did not work too (I also could not use a finite state machine on the SPI ISR).

**The Code:** 
Variables/arrays used in the SPI Transaction:

```
#define RX_COMMAND_LENGTH       1
#define TX_LENGTH               4

/* The length of the command byte is 1 */
static uint16_t cRxCmdLen = RX_COMMAND_LENGTH;
/* The length of the data to be sent is 4 bytes */
static uint16_t cTxLen = TX_LENGTH;

/* SPI Receive associated variables */
/* pRxBuff will store the received command byte */
static volatile uint8_t pRxBuff[RX_COMMAND_LENGTH] = {0x00};
/* pTempRxBuff will store the 4 irrelevant bytes from master */
static uint8_t pTempRxBuff[TX_LENGTH] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00};

/* SPI Send associated variables */
/* Send 0x99 in exchange for the command byte from master */
static const uint8_t dummybyte[1] = {0x99};
/* Send the 4 bytes to the master if slave receives 0xE1 */
static const uint8_t pTxBuff[TX_LENGTH] = {0xEB, 0x00, 0xCC, 0x01};

/* Flag to process data in while loop */
volatile FlagStatus ExchangeMessage = RESET;
```

SPI Initialization:

```
/* STM32F3 uses PLL to get HCLK to 64MHz */

static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{
   /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
   hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
   hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_SLAVE;
   hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
   hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
   hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
   hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_2EDGE;
   hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
   hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_16;
   hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
   hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
   hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
   hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
   hspi1.Init.CRCLength = SPI_CRC_LENGTH_DATASIZE;
   hspi1.Init.NSSPMode = SPI_NSS_PULSE_DISABLE;
   if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
   {
      Error_Handler();
   }

   /* Set spi interrupt priority and enable spi interrupts */
   HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI1_IRQn, 1, 1);
   HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);
}
```

SPI Slave ISR:

```
void HAL_SPI_TxRxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi) {

   /* SPI1 peripheral communicates with master */
   if(hspi->Instance == SPI1){

      /* If command byte received is 0xE1 */
      if(pRxBuff[0] == 0xE1) {

         /* Activate flag to trigger SPI exchange data process in main loop */
         ExchangeMessage = SET;
      }
      else {
         /* Ignore received garbage value */

         /* Configure mcu to listen for command bytes */   
         HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)dummybyte, (uint8_t*)pRxBuff, cRxCmdLen);
      }
   }
}
```

The main loop:

```
while(1) {
   if(ExchangeMessage == SET) {
      /* Transmit the 4 bytes to the master in exchange for the 4 dummy/irrelevant bytes */
      HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)pTxBuff, (uint8_t*)pTempRxBuff, cTxLen, 10);

      /* Reset flag */
      ExchangeMessage = RESET;

      /* Configure mcu to be ready for command bytes */
      HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT(&hspi1, (uint8_t*)dummybyte, (uint8_t*)pRxBuff, cRxCmdLen);
   }
}
```

This is the manual SPI transaction code I tried based on one of the ST threads that did not work on the slave (but worked on the master):

```
uint8_t ExchangeSpiBits(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t xSendData) {
   uint8_t retval = 0x00;

   /* Loop until Tx buffer is empty */
   while( !(hspi->Instance->SR & SPI_FLAG_TXE));

   /* Write to SPI Data Register */
   *((__IO uint8_t*)&hspi->Instance->DR) = xSendData;

   /* Loop until Tx buffer is empty */
   while( !(hspi->Instance->SR & SPI_FLAG_TXE));

   /* Loop until SPI is not busy */
   while( (hspi->Instance->SR & SPI_FLAG_BSY));

   /* Loop until Rx buffer is empty */
   while( (hspi->Instance->SR & SPI_FLAG_RXNE)){
      /* Retrieve data from SPI Data Register */
      retval = hspi->Instance->DR;
   }

   return retval;
}
```

I have ran out of ideas on how to make the STM32F3 Slave send data properly. I also do not know what other sync issues I might be missing. Currently, I believe that the error is the slave device and not the master as the master transmits the correct sequence of data all the time. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you logic analyser is trying to sample the slave data on the same clock edge which the slave used to change to the next bit. Are you sure you have both ends of the link configured to the correct SPI mode? Does your slave have a 'chip-select' driven by the master?

Comment: @brhans correct SPI modes as in CPOL and CPHA? They are both configured to `SPI_POLARITY_LOW` and `SPI_PHASE_2EDGE`. I actually do not have a 'chip-select' driven by the master. Would it be necessary in this case as the master is only communicating with one slave, and the slave is also programmed in SPI receive interrupt mode? I started the simulation with simple SPI interrupts and I found out that if I were to only send data from the master to the slave, the slave would receive the data correctly every time without any CS pin. Thanks

Comment: On the StackExchange sites, there is no thing like a "thread" as these are not forums. You post a specific question, and with some luck, there will be an answer. If you have a new or following question, post a new question. It's that simple. You might like to link to the previous question or any answer of it, if you see fit.

Comment: Well if you used the chip-select in the slave then you'd never have the problem you show in the 2nd-last pic where the bytes are 'shifted'. The chip-select would reset the state logic in the slave so that it would always respond with the appropriate byte sequence starting with 0x99.

Comment: And if the bytes received by your master from the slave look in any way similar to the way your logic analyzer is decoding them then you do not have them both configured correctly with regard to the SPI mode (clock polarity & edge). You can see by comparing your analyzer 1st 2 traces that the slave is sending out the same logic levels in both of them - so how are they being interpreted differently? If the analyzer (and presumably your master too) are trying to latch the MISO data bit on the same clock edge which the slave uses to change to the next data bit then you're bound to have trouble.

Comment: You need to make sure that each side latches its incoming data on the clock edge where that data is *stable*, and not on the same clock edge on which the other side is changing to the next bit.

Comment: @thebusybee I see, thanks for explaining how stackoverflow works!

Comment: @brhans Thanks for the suggestions. I looked further into it and it turns out that the logic analyzer is the one configured incorrectly. I did not notice how the waveforms were the same when running new tests because I did not save screenshots of the waveforms before. I changed the logic analyzer's config to CPOL = 0 and CPHA = 1 and all the waveforms produced are as expected.

Comment: @brhans I think I was also too focused on the code that I did not even consider that the logic analyzer was the one that was configured incorrectly. Regarding the chip-select implementation in the slave, I still do not understand how the bytes could be shifted without it. Isn't the first `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT()` purpose to exchange 0x99 from the slave with 0xE1 from the master? Since everything is configured through software I would imagine that using CS would be redundant as I would have to use GPIO interrupts instead of SPI interrupts? Thanks

Comment: The purpose of CS to the slave would be to *ensure* that the slave's "state machine" is guaranteed to reset and always respond with the initial 0x99 like it's supposed to - even if previous attempts at communication failed or were truncated for some reason. From your 'shifted' traces it looks like there's a byte that's "gone missing" somehow between the slave and the master, and without CS you'll never recover from that situation (unless you manage to 'lose' another 4 bytes somehow).

Comment: @brhans I think I get it now. Would that mean that the better approach is to just use GPIO interrupts to enable the SPI peripheral and run `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive()` in blocking mode, then disabling the SPI peripheral when CS is set high?

Comment: I'd use a GPIO interrupt to enable SPI and start the 1st `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive_IT()`. Depends on what else your slave is doing whether or not you use blocking SPI or interrupt-driven.

Comment: @brhans Thanks for the input! I'll try that approach